# Selecting which data models sync with iCloud SwiftData

Tags: icloud, cloudkit, swift-data

So I am trying to sync only some of my Models with iCloud and others kept locally in the default.store. I am having a world of issues so before I start looking for the needle in my haystack. I would like to ask this forum, is my approach one that should work as desired or is my code obviously why things are not working? All my Models have default values and relationships where needed are optionals. iCloud is working but my issue arises when i try to exclude some models. So I want to sync "modelsForCloudSyncing" but not "modelNotForCloudSyncing" In advance thank you

```
    var avoidCloudSyncModelContainer : ModelContainer = {

let modelNotForCloudSyncing = Schema([NoCloudSyncModel.self])

let modelConfigForNoCloudSync = ModelConfiguration(schema: modelNotForCloudSyncing, cloudKitDatabase: .none)


let modelsForCloudSyncing = Schema([CloudSyncModelA.self, CloudSyncModelB.self, CloudSyncModelC.self])

let modelConfigForCloudSync = ModelConfiguration(schema: modelsForCloudSyncing, cloudKitDatabase: .automatic)




do {
  return try ModelContainer(for: NoCloudSyncModel.self, CloudSyncModelA.self, CloudSyncModelB.self, CloudSyncModelC.self, configurations: modelConfigForNoCloudSync, modelConfigForCloudSync)
   }
catch { fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)") }

}()






   ...
{
ContentView()
}.modelContainer(avoidCloudSyncModelContainer)
```